# Can remote mysql operate write command?

Tags: database, laravel, remote-access, remote-server

Can remote mysql operate write command ???
I want to write on the database of another server which I allowed for remotely access.
Can write command run on remote method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can insert data on the database for which you have remote access. Just make sure the user of the database have the write permissions.
If you want to know about how to do it programatically,then please specify the technology in which you want to use.